# ElasticSearch Term Frequency across two fields

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I have the elastic search query below that gives me an appropriate result set. However, the data has very few number of 'ArticleTest' content types. The tag match and term frequency boosts are causing all of those documents to shoot to the top of the list when there are 'ArticleBasic' content that is more relevant or that have a higher number of tag matches.

Is there a way I can tell elastic search to consider both fields when calculating term frequency boosts?

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "contenttype": "ArticleTest"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "contenttype": "ArticleBasic"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "wildcard": {
                  "ArticleBasic.tags": "*history*"
                }
              },
              {
                "wildcard": {
                  "ArticleBasic.tags": "*meet locals*"
                }
              },
              {
                "wildcard": {
                  "ArticleBasic.tags": "*nature & wildlife*"
                }
              },
              {
                "wildcard": {
                  "ArticleBasic.tags": "*|north-america|canada|quebec-city*"
                }
              },
              {
                "wildcard": {
                  "ArticleBasic.tags": "*|north-america|canada|churchill*"
                }
              },
              {
                "wildcard": {
                  "ArticleBasic.tags": "*|north-america|canada|manitoba*"
                }
              },
              {
                "wildcard": {
                  "ArticleBasic.tags": "*|north-america|canada|alberta*"
                }
              },
              {
                "wildcard": {
                  "ArticleTest.tags": "*history*"
                }
              },
              {
                "wildcard": {
                  "ArticleTest.tags": "*meet locals*"
                }
              },
              {
                "wildcard": {
                  "ArticleTest.tags": "*nature & wildlife*"
                }
              },
              {
                "wildcard": {
                  "ArticleTest.tags": "*|north-america|canada|quebec-city*"
                }
              },
              {
                "wildcard": {
                  "ArticleTest.tags": "*|north-america|canada|churchill*"
                }
              },
              {
                "wildcard": {
                  "ArticleTest.tags": "*|north-america|canada|manitoba*"
                }
              },
              {
                "wildcard": {
                  "ArticleTest.tags": "*|north-america|canada|alberta*"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "identifier": "b05e28402b854b9221f08daa81e99b61"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": "desc"
    },
    {
      "_script": {
        "type": "number",
        "script": "if(doc['ArticleTest.publish'].size() != 0) { return doc['ArticleTest.publish'].value.millis; }else if(doc['ArticleBasic.publish'].size() != 0) { return doc['ArticleBasic.publish'].value.millis; }else { return 0; }",
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "size": 5,
  "from": 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

I don't think there is.

## Solutions ?

How about merging both fields ?
By using the [copy_to](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html) to copy both fields into a single one. This way the term frequency is done on both fields (virtually)